# Javascript Detect an href change

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, document-ready

I am trying to have my JavaScript check to see if a background is loaded (loaded by jquery.ready function, if the background or the background div is loaded then i want it to set 2 href links, if the background fails to load or something goes wrong then the hrefs are set to nothing or #. I have done a few different ways and tried to mix and match some code but it seems i can't get it to work right. Any help would be great, i have search high and low on google, here and have tried for a while to make the code work in one way or another.

again thanks!

Comment: potential duplicates:[How to use jQuery to detect loaded background image after inserting out CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4337738/how-to-use-jquery-to-detect-loaded-background-image-after-inserting-out-css), [Javascript event css background image loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560750/javascript-event-css-background-image-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess that when say you background, what you're refering to is a background image. I don't believe there are any Javascript events related to background image loading that will accomplish the effect you mentioned. The jQuery onReady and load functions allow you to bind to the document itself, and will only fire once the entire page and all its external resources have loaded. However, this might help:

[Image onload for static images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632765/image-onload-for-static-images)

Comment: what about checking the div the background image is loaded into?

Answer (score 0):

I think a more direct route may be to load your image in an `<img />` tag in your jQuery script and handle the onerror event.  This way you can still set the background the way you are currently but this will allow you to determine programmatically if the image path is valid.

example on handling the onerror event for an image [jQuery/Javascript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

**edit:** here's an example of how to use images to detect errors http://jsfiddle.net/DHEqe/35/